# Lumen - Cargar las relaciones de un modelo

Tags: json, relaciones, lumen

Necesito poder cargar las relaciones de un modelo en una sola respuesta y no he buscando como, según veo en la documentación es con "load" pero no me funciona.
En otras palabras es: que cuando pida el hotel me regrese los datos del hotel mas sus imagenes

Modelo Hotel

```
public function imgHotel(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ImgHotel', 'IdHotel','IdHotel');
```

Model imgHotel

```
public function hotel(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hotel', 'IdHotel','IdHotel');
```

en el controlador de hotel en el metodo show

```
Hotel::findOrFail($hotel_id);
```

y ya no se como añadirle las imagenes a la respuesta. trato de hacer algo asi

```
    $hotel = Hotel::findOrFail($hotel_id);
    $hotel['imagenes'] = $hotel->imgHotel;
```

cabe mencionar que esto es para una api y es una salida json

Answer (score 0):

lo puede resolver de esta forma

```
$hotel = Hotel::with('imgHotel')->whereIn('IdHotel', [$hotel_id])->get();
```

Aun que tambien se puede hacer con setAttribute y quedaria asi

```
$hotel = Hotel::findOrFail($hotel_id);
$hotel->setAttribute('img_hotel',$hotel->imgHotel);
```